# Loop through an array of Asynchronous javascript functions Synchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, synchronization

I have an array of asynchronous ajax calls that i need to loop through and execute in order. Is there a way to do this avoiding promises?

Here is what i have, this works but doesnt wait until the last post is complete

```
for (i = 0; i < post.length; i++)
{
   post[i]();
};
```

Comment: The question isn't really if there's any way to do it, the quesion is if you *should* do it, and the answer is always ***no*** !

Comment: unfortunately im restricted to doing it this way because of how the system was designed

Comment: No you're not, you're never restricted to doing ajax synchronously.

Comment: the system is setup doing ajax calls synchronously, after changing the calls to asynchronous on all, the system tries to validate before post so it has nothing to validate because validate gets called before post. Its server side validation, so i was just looking for a workaround.

Comment: Could you clarify why you want to avoid promises?

Comment: so the way the system is setup is that it is looping through items and doing sync ajax calls, these ajax calls are within a wrapper function that doesnt return a promise and is being used elsewhere. No sure if i can avoid them?

Comment: I use Bluebird's promisification to convert callback-code to Promises. Check out http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html - it fixes 99.9% of libs I encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear on why you cannot use promises, but if you are able to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
post.forEach( async currentPost => {
  await currentPost()
})
```

If you aren't using promises because they are a pain and they are verbose, then the above might be a little more to your liking.

If you aren't able to use async/await because of browsers that don't understand promises, then this won't work because [async functions return promises](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8). But [on many modern browsers, compatibility is good](http://caniuse.com/#search=await).

Comment: He could use polyfills if compatibility is an issue.

Comment: True story. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transform your code before deploying, or polyfills (e.g., https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) can help with compatibility.

Comment: The best approach would be a `Promise`, chaining them with `.then()`, `Promise.all()` or `async/await` but I don't get why he wants to avoid them. If is about compatibility, Babel solves that.

Comment: async/await is just syntactic sugar.